# Trying To assign datalist in one step instead of two, destructuring problem

Tags: javascript

I have the following lines of code to start with:

```
 var temp = {
    speakers: {
      datalist: [9, 8, 7, 6]
    }
  };
  const {speakers} = temp;
  const datalist = speakers.datalist;
  if (datalist.length === 4) console.log("success");
```

I can't figure out the JavaScript syntax that let's me get datalist directly from temp.

I'm thinking it's something like:

```
const {speakers.datalist} = temp;
```

But obviously that's wrong.

In other words, I  want

```
const datalist = <some expression that involves temp>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `const {speakers: {datalist}} = temp;`

```js
var temp = {
  speakers: {
    datalist: [9, 8, 7, 6]
  }
};
const {speakers: {datalist}} = temp;

console.log(datalist)
```